# WPF - automatic view resolving for view model

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I created library for Android that makes use of MVVM pattern easier.

In my library I have special `ViewManager` class responsible for resolving appropriate view for given view model. Let me give you an example:

```
ViewManager.register(ViewModel.class, View.class);  // ViewModel will be now presented by View.
// Now when, for example, tabbed view item will be "new ViewModel()"; it will automatically be presented by View.class
```

What would be a proper way to achieve that in WPF, so if i bind my `TabControl` items to collection of view models, it will automatically resolve appropriate view to display them from my `ViewManager`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any of that code to do that in WPF... you can do it quite simply and easily by declaring `DataTemplate`s in the `App.xaml` file:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type YourViewModelsPrefix:YourViewModel">
    <YourViewsPrefix:YourView />
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type YourViewModelsPrefix:YourOtherViewModel">
    <YourViewsPrefix:YourOtherView />
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type YourViewModelsPrefix:AnotherViewModel">
    <YourViewsPrefix:AnotherView />
</DataTemplate>
```

Now whenever the Framework comes across an instance of these view model classes, it will render the associated view. You can display them by having a property of the type of your view model using a `ContentControl` like this:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding YourViewModelProperty}" />
```